# Make Spring SAML SP work with other port than 8080

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml, idp

I'm using this [sample project from vdenotaris](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) as the SP, and I'm building a POC of an IDP using spring boot. I ran into an issue which was answerered by the repo owner [here](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/issues/35)

However I don't need to register yet my SP on the IDP (since the IDP isn't implemented) but my end project needs to run on the port 8080, and that's causing me conflicts with the Service Provider (sample project), how can I make it work for another port?
Vincenzo states in the issue the following:

The application is pre-registered on SSO Circle, with localhost:8080 as endpoint (static).
If you would like to use another port, you need to:

> - change the default EntityId
> - make a brand-new registration on SSO Circle (or any other IdP)

But I don't understand how to change the default EntityId

What have I tried so far? adding `server.port=9090` to the application.properties, and I'm able to run his project just fine, but when I send the assertion back from the IDP => SP I keep getting a 404..

I'm kinda new into Java and Spring so any help will be great, I'm stuck in here.

Comment: Did you try hitting the SP end-point using curl with the saml response? It can be that it's actually 404, resource not found.

Comment: A side note. The spring-security-saml2-core will be EOL soon. They have added the SP support within the Spring Security iteself now. So its better to use it from the Spring Security itself https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2

Comment: I did not looked into the repo linked in the question in detail but you can take reference to https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-security-saml-test-identity-provider-and-service-provider repo that I created a while ago. This lists both SP and IDP with Spring Security SAML 3(now no longer maintained). You can use the IDP from this repo to test your SP system with ease (without requiring a third party IDP)